# Android device requires PIN code after running CTS

Tags: android, cts

I ran CTS PLAN and after it finished, I saw that my Android device asked me enter a PIN code to access the device. However, I didn't set a PIN to lock the device, and I don't know which PIN I'm supposed to provide.

This problem happened to me on 2 more Android devices when I ran CTS on them. 
I tried some passwords but they have not solved this.

I'm looking for a solution to this problem, but can't find any other mention of this problem.

NOTE: I ran CTS with a script, but has it really change something?

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue,I entered pin as 12345.It's worked for me try from your side and let me know

Comment: thank you! next time the device will be locked, i will try it